# How can I store different pieces of information depending on a user's role in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET's built-in identities system.  And I want to have different types of users.  ASP.NET already allows me to create user roles, but I also want to store different types of data depending on which role the user has.

For example, a **customer** can have a balance, while a **supplier** can have a company name.  But both are users which should be able to log into my system.  Is there a good way to do this in ASP.NET?

Comment: You definitely need to learn how the identity framework is built around **claims**. What you describe sounds exactly like claims but in the same time you sound like you are unaware of their existence.

Comment: do you need it persistent across logins, or only for the current session?

Answer (score 0):

Use the asp.net identity profile API to add custom properties for your users.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on#ap

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // start custom properties
    public string HomeTown { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    // end custom properties
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

This post from the asp.net team has a more step by step approach.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx